# SCM Manger- Where does the source code files store in Server?

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to git. I have created a repository in SCM manager and pushed code to Origin. When I see the repo path [..\scm-manager\repositories\git ] at server, I found only git related files not my code.

I was under the impression that my entire source code actually stored in SCM server after I pushed the files.

If files are not physically stored at SCM server, where does it exactly store ?

However, I am able to see my files in SCM UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository on the server is a so-called [bare repository](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).Such a repository does not contain a working directory.

But all the files are stored as [git objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Comment: Thanks Roland, What would be best method to define repositories at server side ? Will it be in bare repository format or working directory with post-receive hooks?

Comment: On the server side you should use bare repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The whole repository resides in the .git directory. What you see (additionally) on your local machine is the working directory with the revision you currently have checked-out and on which you might be working.

The contents are in the files in the subdirectories of `.git/objects`, and are compressed with zlib.

Comment: Thanks planetmaker, if all repository contents are stored within .git directory, I am wondering the size of the actual repo is around 524MB, but the .git folder in server is just 90MB. Is it in highly compressed format?


 I have not checked out / cloned few repositories in my local, but still I am able to open those files in my SCM UI.

Comment: I'm not familiar with git internals. However for text files like code it is easy to get good compression ratios.

Comment: @Kumar the data in the `.git/objects` subdirectories is compressed with `zlib`.